# CAML XML data source not pulling all rows from a web service GetListItem

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, caml

I have a CAML query looking at a XML sharepoint data source. The below is my query which does pull results out, but not all columns and some looks to be in a strange format [image].

It doesnt seem to pick up all my list item columns from the data source. Can anyone see anything wrong with my CAML XML ? Pleaase note it is a calendar sharepoint. Is it possible to alter my CAML XML to look at the allitems.aspx page which is a list of the calendar view.

```
<Query>
<SoapAction>http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems</SoapAction>
  <Method Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" Name="GetListItems">
    <Parameters>
      <Parameter Name="listName">
        <DefaultValue>Change Control</DefaultValue>
      </Parameter>
      <Parameter Name="queryOptions" Type="xml">
        <DefaultValue>
          <QueryOptions>
                      <ViewAttributes Scope="Recursive" />
         </QueryOptions>
        </DefaultValue>
      </Parameter>
    </Parameters>
  </Method>
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you're missing the `viewFields` parameter, which is how you customize the Fields that are included in a GetListItems response. The possible parameters for a GetListItems request are ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems.aspx)):

```
public XmlNode GetListItems (
    string listName,
    string viewName,
    XmlNode query,
    XmlNode viewFields,
    string rowLimit,
    XmlNode queryOptions,
    string webID
)
```

You've got a `listName` and `queryOptions` already so you have the structure you need; just add another parameter and populate it as needed. Ex:

```
<Parameter Name="viewFields" Type="xml">
    <DefaultValue>
        <ViewFields>
            <FieldRef Name="Field1" />
            <FieldRef Name="Field2" />
            ...
        </ViewFields>
    </DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
```